# MYSQL Subctract Days and Seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Greeting all

I update my field 'createdOn' datetime field to hold values of last 7 days in random like this:

```
UPDATE posts
   SET createdOn
     = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL ROUND(RAND()*7) DAY)
```

Although this gives me the random dates I need, the hours, minutes and seconds are not random and are like 00:00:00. How can I include random hours, minutes and seconds also in the above? **Unique** hours, minutes and seconds in the last seven days would be even better.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an example of random hours, minites and seconds in the last seven days -

```
UPDATE posts
  SET createdOn = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 604800) SECOND;
```

Where 604800 = 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting `NOW()` as a `DATE`, which will strip out the time portion, and force it to 00:00:00. Perhaps do another `RAND()` on `TIME(NOW())` and adding them together.